# Customize Tailwind Breaktpoints for high resolution and high PPI screens

Tags: tailwind-css, breakpoints

I'm working on a website with tailwind. On a regular external 4K screen everything looks according to the design. But there are some 4K screens with high PPI (e.g. 4K laptops with a smaller screen).
Due to the smaller available space on such devices everything looks really crowded.

How can i extend tailwind so that there is a simple media query (like 2xl:) which asks for a min-screen size and a min-device-pixel-ratio?

I know there is CSS media query for DPR:
`@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You can [customize](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#custom-media-queries) media screens with `raw` keyword

> If you want full control over the generated media query, use the raw key

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        dpr: {
          raw: 'only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)'
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Usage: `dpr:utility`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into official docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

Change your `tailwind.config.js` to:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'tablet': '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      'laptop': '1024px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }

      'desktop': '1280px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve my issue. it only sets the min-width for the breakpoint, but not the DPI